# Can a Wasm executable be encrypted to prevent reverse engineering?

Tags: binary, executable, webassembly

Can a Wasm executable be encrypted to prevent it being reverse engineered?

Comment: Why need encryption? For example Windows executables can be encrypted, but there are tools to automatically decrypt these.

Comment: WASM allows the developer to move business logic off of the server and into a multithreaded executable on the client, this has many performance and scaling benefits, but the one remaining advantage of keeping the business logic on the back-end is that proprietary code cannot be accessed directly and/or reverse engineered.

Comment: But that hold also trough for windows executables. Whenever logic is executed und end users own hardware it can be decrypted and reverse engineered. Only way to avoid this is seending own hardware or only allow access von non open system. With wasm you can reverse Engineering more difficult. It is same as for Java: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077342/cracking-java-byte-code-encryption.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the specification and browser-based implementations do not have native support for binary encryption. However, if you're running a Wasm module *outside* the browser, you can in theory implement encryption on the module compilation side and decryption on any number of Wasm runtimes. I believe some of the blockchain implementations are looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no such facility right now